# How to access page title in selenium via element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DriverExp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/ConsultingAgency/");
        WebElement webelem = driver.findElement(By.tagName("title"));
        System.out.println(
                 "TagName: " + webelem.getTagName()
                + "\nText: " + webelem.getText()
                + "\nText: " + webelem.getAttribute("value"));

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I'm working on Eclipse, with selenium 2.42 and Firefox 30.0
The main page with the url `http://localhost:8080/ConsultingAgency/` has a nonempty title, but I don't know how to get it value.

My result return an empty string.
I want to access by webelem object, not by driver.getTitle() method. Does it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` is in the page's header. `findElement(By.tagName("title"))` looks through the page's body. You will need to use `driver.getTitle()`.